# Reading integer as character & printing it as integer

Tags: c, scanf

Output of this snippet is **32566** for the input **65**.
please explain the concept behind it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char ch;
  int i;
  scanf("%c", &i);
  printf("%d",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you know about the conversion specifiers?

Comment: As a matter of interest, which compiler (and C standard, if you know) are you using?  On my stock gcc 4.8.4, this does not happen.

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
   scanf("%c", &i);
```

causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You are supplying an invalid type of argument to `%c` conversion specifier.

`%c` expects a pointer to a character type as corresponding argument, but you supply a pointer to an integer.

Comment: But, why it's printing 32566?

Answer (score 2):

Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior. Here you are doing the same thing.

You should read it like this

```
scanf("%d",&i); // because you are reading an integer.
```

On your case you write

```
scanf("%c", &i);
```

You are passing an address of an int variable but here `%c` is supposed to get an address of a char variable. That discrepancy gives the undefined behavior.

To give you a better idea - `scanf` expects a format speicifer and an address. from an address there is no way `scanf()` will understand what kind of data it needs to parse. But yes the format specifier tells that. So in this case on passing the wrong format specifier it messes up.

Comment: I am indeed.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dnij.png)

You forgot initialze the variable 'i'. Than the program runs correctly

Answer (score -2):

Your program reads the ascii-code of letter 'A'. If you change the format symbol '%d' in '%c' than the output is 'A'.

If you initialize the variable i with 0. Output is 65, if you enter 'A'

Comment: no, I have try the snippet. And I have init the variable 'i'. Than it works.

Comment: You are right, my apologies.  Interestingly, on my system I don't even have to initialize the variable for the snippet to work correctly.